# systemd support scripts path

Tags: linux, systemd

I'm in the process of switching the init system of our yocto-based distro from SysV init to systemd. While going through some of our old SysV init bash scripts, I realized I cannot get rid of these scripts completely - sometimes there are some actions that need to be performed before invoking the service's executable (i.e. reading a value of a u-boot environment variable etc.). Also, it cannot be separated into distinct steps (meaning moving some parts into ExecStartPre), because the service's executable needs to run in the same environment (i.e. the u-boot variable value will be passed to it as an argument). So I'll end up with some "wrapper" bash scripts, which do these steps and at the very end `exec` the main executable.

Is there any recommended place for such scripts? I don't want to keep them in the old `/etc/init.d`, neither do I want to put them into `/bin`, `/sbin` or their equivalents under `/usr` - any of these locations might be tempting the user to execute them, and I want to avoid that. I would prefer to keep the files in a path which is dedicated for that particular systemd unit. The best I could think of was `/lib/systemd/system/<unit>.d/` or `/etc/systemd/<unit>.d/`, but I'm not sure if it's a good idea.

Also, as a side question: is there any way how to obtain the unit name from within the unit file, so I could use the name in a path to such script instead of hardcoding it? I guess that an unit instantiated from a template would offer that, but I don't want to use templates for each such unit.

Comment: Side question: See the [Specifiers](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Specifiers) section, e.g. `"%N"` would be the name `foo` of `foo.service` which can be used in the path to the script.

Comment: A lot of non-cli utilities go under per-product directories in `/usr/libexec/`.